# My second Scanf() is being skipped

Tags: c

If my program looks like this:

```
printf("What are your 2 favourite fruits:\n");
scanf("%s", s1);
printf("What are your 2 least favourite fruits:\n");
scanf("%s", s2);
```

and my first Scanf() has a space in it, the second Scanf() gets skipped.

The output would look like this:

What are your 2 favourite fruits:
Apples and Oranges

What are your 2 least favourite fruits:
(doesn't wait for input)

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: What *is* your actual input? What do you mean by "skipped"? Have you checked what the function calls return? What is `s1` and `s2`? And *please* try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: avoid using `&` before `s1` and `s2` as they are strings.

Comment: Works fine for me (removing the `&` from the second argument, since they are pointers).

Comment: Note that `%s` reads up to the first white space.  Given the input 'Apples and Oranges', the first call would read 'Apples' and the second 'and' (leaving 'Oranges' to be processed by anything later).  You'd be able to see this if you printed out what was read as it was read (`printf("Got: [%s]\n", s1);` after the first `scanf()`, etc.).  If you want to read whole lines, use `fgets()`. Watch out for the trailing newline.

Comment: Read *carefully* the documentation of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). You should use its result (number of successfully scanned items) and check for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`scanf()` with `%s` does not accept strings containing white-spaces.**
For strings having white-spaces, use `fgets()` or `scanf("%[^\n]s", string);`
This would read everything until newline character '`\n`'.

For example:

```
printf("What are your 2 favourite fruits:\n");
scanf("%[^\n]s", s1);
printf("What are your 2 least favourite fruits:\n");
scanf("%[^\n]s", s2);
```

Comment: Note that `%[^\n]` is sufficient to read up to a newline.  The `s` never matches anything, but you can never tell that it failed, either.  (In other words, `%[^\n]` is the complete conversion specification; the square brackets are not a modifier for the `%s` conversion specification but are a completely separate conversion specification.  Amongst other differences, `%[^\n]` does not skip leading spaces, unlike `%s` which does.  I would say "`%s` skips leading white space, and then matches a sequence of one or more non-white space characters, stopping at the next white space".